# "Pic courtesy of Jessica Drake and @GloriaAllred" means?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I see it from [this article](https://www.yahoo.com/news/report-porn-star-said-yearlong-affair-trump-2006-182958520.html). I don't understand what **Pic courtesy of Jessica Drake and @GloriaAllred** means.

> Drake with #DonaldTrump at Tahoe event in 2006. **Pic courtesy** of Jessica Drake and @GloriaAllred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *pic* is just a short way to say *picture*. If something is provided [**courtesy of someone or some organization**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/courtesy-of-someone), it means that they gave it to you (typically free of charge) because you requested them to give it to you for the purposes of using it in something like a book or a news article. More often than not, mass publications such as books and newspapers are actually where you see this expression used most often. Its purpose is to acknowledge the fact that a picture, photograph, drawing etc. was not a result of the author's own work, but was rather given to them by a third party. For example:

> Picture courtesy of NASA Image and Video Library

This means that the picture you're looking at was not made by the author himself, but was given to him or her by an organization called NASA Image and Video Library because they needed it for their book. Notice that there is no *the* before and *is* after *picture*. It's very standard in English to omit those little things in "pro forma" language.

So, here's what your original passage is saying:

> The picture you're looking at is courtesy of (was provided by) individuals named Jessica Drake and @GloriaAllred (Internet nickname).